# import matplotlib failed in Anaconda python3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, subprocess, anaconda

I installed Anaconda to simplify the management of many python modules.

After that i tried to "import subprocess":

```
>>> import subprocess
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sej/.config/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 155, in <module>
    _PopenSelector = selectors.SelectSelector
AttributeError: module 'selectors' has no attribute 'SelectSelector'
```

How to fix this?

I came accross this problem by trying to use matplotlib.
When trying to import it, this error comes up:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sej/.config/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
  File "/home/sej/.config/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/compat/subprocess.py", line 27, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/home/sej/.config/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 155, in <module>
    _PopenSelector = selectors.SelectSelector
AttributeError: module 'selectors' has no attribute 'SelectSelector'
```

Comment: Note that the problem is independent of matplotlib. I edited the question to make this clearer. For someone to look into this, it would help if you added more information about your system, how you installed anaconda, if there were previous versions installed etc.

Comment: I tried a lot to solve the problem - upgrade all relevant packages (no success); downgrade matplotlib to any version (no access) upgrade python, and so on ... many many hours. After all i did a complete new installation, updated all upgradable modules/packages - and look: NO ERROR. The problem before is still unclear but what else...