# Terminal cannot run selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, terminal

I wrote a python program that uses selenium. When I run it with spyder, it works perfectly. But when I run it on Terminal, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/Documents/Python Projects/school.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .webelement import WebElement
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 27, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common.utils import keys_to_typing
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 21, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 11, in <module>
    import math
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/Documents/Python Projects/math.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py", line 20, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/platform.py", line 116, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, subprocess
  File "/Users/aldrin0n9/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in <module>
    _PopenSelector = selectors.SelectSelector
AttributeError: module 'selectors' has no attribute 'SelectSelector'
```

Please help

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609024/import-matplotlib-failed-in-anaconda-python3-6) for a similar problem. It's likely to do with flawed installation, version issues

Comment: My bad, I realized I made a super amateur mistake. If you pay attention to the error message. You can see that when import math is called, a python file in my documents is called instead of the official math python file. This is because last week I accidentally named one file math.py.